# Create a selectpicker using javascript

Tags: javascript

What I do is delete the select and I want to recreate the select with the selectpicker class and then create options by adding the object that I have in each

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('sati/mostrartelegestores');?>",
    type: "POST",
    data: fechas,
    success: function(data) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);

        $("#selector_telegestor").remove();

        var $select = $('<select/>', {
            'class': "selectpicker"
        });

        $.each(obj, function(i, item) {
            $select.append("<option value=" + item.usuario.trim() + ">" + item.usuario.trim() + "</option>");
        });

         $select.selectpicker('refresh');
    }
});


<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <label class=" text-center" for="selector_telegestor"><?php echo $traduccion["TELEGESTOR"];?></label>
                    <select class="selectpicker form-control" name="selector_telegestor" id="selector_telegestor" multiple>
                        <div id="telegestores">

                        </div>  
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The moment you `remove()` the DOM element you don't be able to find it later on. You need to add your `$select` after the original element using [`after()`](https://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)... and **then** you can remove the original element

Comment: Although, you are recreating the select, you don't give it an id or add it back in to the DOM, meaning it cannot be found by `$("#selector_telegestor")`. Why don't you just remove and re-add it's options instead?

Comment: @phuzi what I want is to delete the original and create a new one with the same class and the same id as the original that I deleted at the beginning

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't/how to make this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and _the shortest code necessary to **reproduce it in the question itself**_. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: @LGSon I've already added the bootstrap part

Comment: Well, you haven't provide a [mcve] ... and having a `div` as a child of a `select` is invalid syntax

Comment: @LGSon This code is the one I have I have no more ...

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to give your new `select` all the same attributes as the original, then you'll need to add it back in to the DOM.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#selector_telegestor").selectpicker();
  
  $('#refresh').on('click', refresh);
  
});

function refresh(){
        var obj = [ { 'usuario': 'refresh1' }, { 'usuario': 'refresh2' }, { 'usuario': 'refresh3' }];

        // re-create the select with the same attributes etc.
        var $select = $('<select/>', {
          'class': 'selectpicker form-control',
          'name': 'selector_telegestor',
          'id': 'selector_telegestor',
          'multiple': true
        });

        $.each(obj, function(i, item) {
          let opt = $('<option/>', {
            'value': item.usuario.trim()
          })
          .text(item.usuario.trim());
          
          $select.append(opt);
        });

        // replace existing select with the new one
        $("#selector_telegestor")
          .selectpicker('destroy')
          .replaceWith($select);
          
        $select.selectpicker('refresh');
}

/*
    $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo site_url('sati/mostrartelegestores');?>",
      type: "POST",
      data: fechas,
      success: function(data) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);

        // re-create the select with the same attributes etc.
        var $select = $('<select/>', {
          'class': 'selectpicker form-control',
          'name': 'selector_telegestor',
          'id': 'selector_telegestor',
          'multiple': true
        });

        $.each(obj, function(i, item) {
          let opt = $('<option/>', {
            'value': item.usuario.trim()
          })
          .text(item.usuario.trim());
          
          $select.append(opt);
        });

        // replace existing select with the new one
        $("#selector_telegestor").replaceWith($select);
        $select.selectpicker('refresh');
      }
    });
*/
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.11/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.11/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>



<select class="selectpicker form-control" name="selector_telegestor" id="selector_telegestor" multiple>
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Barbecue</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="refresh" value="Refresh"/>
```

**Update**

When replacing the select, don't forget to `.selectpicker('destroy')` the original.

Also replaced with a minimally complete and verifiable example.

Comment: I did not delete the previous Select https://gyazo.com/5bfbb11b4036a99bf43cfabb5e8d388e

Comment: `$("#selector_telegestor").remove()` is effectively the same thing, it's removed from the DOM and not re-added. After removing it from the DOM `$("#selector_telegestor")` will not find it.

Comment: Already, but the original is not deleted, the original exists ... and I don't want the original to be seen, if not the new one alone.

Comment: Check out my updated answer, you'll need to `.selectpicker('destroy')` the original selectpicker.